# XBMC Live TV setting to get network iptv channels

Tags: media, xbmc

Im currently running Linux Mint 17-qiana cinnamon, and i wanted to test something that later i want to configure in a home media server that i will build.

The thing is, i have a contract with an internet/phone/tv provider,Vodafone 50MB fiber, and their setup currently is a DVR TV box that is only connected to my router, their box gets the channels, and i was wondering if I could somehow get the channels too and view them with xbmc, hence, building an home media server that would be in my network and i could after that do everything... Visit websites, share content with my laptop... well everythin that a linux computer can do, but it would be connected to my projector so i could watch tv and movies.

The thing here is, i've been looking online and the closest i can get to this is downloading m3u playlists for viewing the channels as if i didnt pay for them, which isn't my plan, since i already pay for the channels, i would like to not have to use their box, and instead connect a computer.

I have noticed there is a channel search feature but only certain add-ons support that, first of all, does anyone know which add-ons support that? Second, would this solve the problem? Could the search find these channels? If this does not solve it, what could do what i want? Would i need to talk to the provider about this? Could they possibly give me access to their m3u playlist? im technically not infringing anything, i'm paying for the service and i only want to integrate it with my system, so i dont see a problem, but on the other hand, i dont know much about this live TV stream, and i'm afraid they might think i want to share this m3u list so people get free TV (i don't know if it is even possible)

Sorry for the long post but most is for context, if there is anything i can clarify, just ask me to and i will.

Thanks,

Comment: If you go to Video, and click the add sources button, does it show up there as e.g. UPnP, DLNA, etc.?

Comment: im not at home so i cant test that right now, but stay tuned, i will reply in about 10-15 minutes, thanks

Comment: BTW: I'm not at home either, and I've only seldom used XBMC... So please forgive me if you have to look around a bit for where exactly that button is. Or what the exact labeling is. Also, that's a guess, I have no idea how Vodafone IPTV works.